# How to create a JSON Web Signature (JWS) with RSA

Tags: java, jwt, nimbus

I was looking to develop / create a **JWT with RSA using Nimbus Jose+Jwt library**. I wanted to use the below version

```
<nimbus-jwt-version>3.1.2</nimbus-jwt-version>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
    <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
    <version>${nimbus-jwt-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

This will create a Token value and also once the token is created it will extracts the claims out of it. Please help with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. Today is 13th-Aug-16 and certainly this is not the latest dependency, today latest dependency is `4.23`. We should need to refactor the code to make it working. Will be posting the logic soon.

```
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.RSAPrivateKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

import com.nimbusds.jose.EncryptionMethod;
import com.nimbusds.jose.JOSEException;
import com.nimbusds.jose.JWEAlgorithm;
import com.nimbusds.jose.JWEHeader;
import com.nimbusds.jose.crypto.RSADecrypter;
import com.nimbusds.jose.crypto.RSAEncrypter;
import com.nimbusds.jwt.EncryptedJWT;
import com.nimbusds.jwt.JWTClaimsSet;

public class JWTNimbusDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator;
        try {
            keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");

            keyPairGenerator.initialize(1024);

            // generate the key pair
            KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.genKeyPair();

            // create KeyFactory and RSA Keys Specs
            KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            RSAPublicKeySpec publicKeySpec = keyFactory.getKeySpec(keyPair.getPublic(), RSAPublicKeySpec.class);
            RSAPrivateKeySpec privateKeySpec = keyFactory.getKeySpec(keyPair.getPrivate(), RSAPrivateKeySpec.class);

            // generate (and retrieve) RSA Keys from the KeyFactory using Keys Specs
            RSAPublicKey publicRsaKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);
            RSAPrivateKey privateRsaKey  = (RSAPrivateKey) keyFactory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);

            JWTClaimsSet claimsSet = new JWTClaimsSet();
            claimsSet.setIssuer("https://my-auth-server.com");
            claimsSet.setSubject("John Kerr");
            claimsSet.setAudience(getAudience());
            claimsSet.setExpirationTime(new Date(new Date().getTime() + 1000*60*10));
            claimsSet.setNotBeforeTime(new Date());
            claimsSet.setJWTID(UUID.randomUUID().toString());

            System.out.println("--------------------------");
            System.out.println("Claim Set : \n"+claimsSet.toJSONObject());

            // create the JWT header and specify:
            //  RSA-OAEP as the encryption algorithm
            //  128-bit AES/GCM as the encryption method
            JWEHeader header = new JWEHeader(JWEAlgorithm.RSA_OAEP, EncryptionMethod.A128GCM);

            // create the EncryptedJWT object
            EncryptedJWT jwt = new EncryptedJWT(header, claimsSet);

            // create an RSA encrypter with the specified public RSA key
            RSAEncrypter encrypter = new RSAEncrypter(publicRsaKey);

            // do the actual encryption
            jwt.encrypt(encrypter);

            // serialize to JWT compact form
            String jwtString = jwt.serialize();
            System.out.println("\nJwt Compact Form : "+jwtString);

            // in order to read back the data from the token using your private RSA key:
            // parse the JWT text string using EncryptedJWT object
            jwt = EncryptedJWT.parse(jwtString);

            // create a decrypter with the specified private RSA key
            RSADecrypter decrypter = new RSADecrypter(privateRsaKey);

            // do the decryption
            jwt.decrypt(decrypter);

            // print out the claims

            System.out.println("===========================================================");
            System.out.println("Issuer: [ " + jwt.getJWTClaimsSet().getIssuer() + "]");
            System.out.println("Subject: [" + jwt.getJWTClaimsSet().getSubject()+ "]");
            System.out.println("Audience size: [" + jwt.getJWTClaimsSet().getAudience().size()+ "]");
            System.out.println("Expiration Time: [" + jwt.getJWTClaimsSet().getExpirationTime()+ "]");
            System.out.println("Not Before Time: [" + jwt.getJWTClaimsSet().getNotBeforeTime()+ "]");
            System.out.println("Issue At: [" + jwt.getJWTClaimsSet().getIssueTime()+ "]");
            System.out.println("JWT ID: [" + jwt.getJWTClaimsSet().getJWTID()+ "]");
            System.out.println("===========================================================");

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException | JOSEException | ParseException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static List<String> getAudience(){
        List<String> audience = new ArrayList<>();
        audience.add("https://my-web-app.com");
        audience.add("https://your-web-app.com");
        return audience;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a "refactored" version of answer of @user4798115 to conform version 4.23:

package com.wf.ocr.service;

```
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.RSAPrivateKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.UUID;

import com.nimbusds.jose.EncryptionMethod;
import com.nimbusds.jose.JOSEException;
import com.nimbusds.jose.JWEAlgorithm;
import com.nimbusds.jose.JWEHeader;
import com.nimbusds.jose.crypto.RSADecrypter;
import com.nimbusds.jose.crypto.RSAEncrypter;
import com.nimbusds.jwt.EncryptedJWT;
import com.nimbusds.jwt.JWTClaimsSet;

import static java.util.Arrays.asList;

public class JWTNimbusDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator;
        try {
            keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");

            keyPairGenerator.initialize(1024);

            // generate the key pair
            KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.genKeyPair();

            // create KeyFactory and RSA Keys Specs
            KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            RSAPublicKeySpec publicKeySpec = keyFactory.getKeySpec(keyPair.getPublic(), RSAPublicKeySpec.class);
            RSAPrivateKeySpec privateKeySpec = keyFactory.getKeySpec(keyPair.getPrivate(), RSAPrivateKeySpec.class);

            // generate (and retrieve) RSA Keys from the KeyFactory using Keys Specs
            RSAPublicKey publicRsaKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);
            RSAPrivateKey privateRsaKey  = (RSAPrivateKey) keyFactory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);

            JWTClaimsSet claimsSet = new JWTClaimsSet.Builder()
                    .issuer("https://openid.net")
                    .subject("alice")
                    .audience(asList("https://my-web-app.com", "https://your-web-app.com"))
                    .expirationTime(new Date(new Date().getTime() + 1000*60*10))
                    .notBeforeTime(new Date())
                    .issueTime(new Date())
                    .jwtID(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                    .build();

            System.out.println("--------------------------");
            System.out.println("Claim Set : \n"+claimsSet.toJSONObject());

            // create the JWT header and specify:
            //  RSA-OAEP as the encryption algorithm
            //  128-bit AES/GCM as the encryption method
            JWEHeader header = new JWEHeader(JWEAlgorithm.RSA_OAEP, EncryptionMethod.A128GCM);

            // create the EncryptedJWT object
            EncryptedJWT jwt = new EncryptedJWT(header, claimsSet);

            // create an RSA encrypter with the specified public RSA key
            RSAEncrypter encrypter = new RSAEncrypter(publicRsaKey);

            // do the actual encryption
            jwt.encrypt(encrypter);

            // serialize to JWT compact form
            String jwtString = jwt.serialize();
            System.out.println("\nJwt Compact Form : "+jwtString);

            // in order to read back the data from the token using your private RSA key:
            // parse the JWT text string using EncryptedJWT object
            jwt = EncryptedJWT.parse(jwtString);

            // create a decrypter with the specified private RSA key
            RSADecrypter decrypter = new RSADecrypter(privateRsaKey);

            // do the decryption
            jwt.decrypt(decrypter);

            // print out the claims

            System.out.println("===========================================================");
            System.out.println("Issuer: [ " + jwt.getJWTClaimsSet().getIssuer() + "]");
            System.out.println("Subject: [" + jwt.getJWTClaimsSet().getSubject()+ "]");
            System.out.println("Audience size: [" + jwt.getJWTClaimsSet().getAudience().size()+ "]");
            System.out.println("Expiration Time: [" + jwt.getJWTClaimsSet().getExpirationTime()+ "]");
            System.out.println("Not Before Time: [" + jwt.getJWTClaimsSet().getNotBeforeTime()+ "]");
            System.out.println("Issue At: [" + jwt.getJWTClaimsSet().getIssueTime()+ "]");
            System.out.println("JWT ID: [" + jwt.getJWTClaimsSet().getJWTID()+ "]");
            System.out.println("===========================================================");

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException | JOSEException | ParseException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```